# VueJS Route Is not defined

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how I can get a hold of the current route because it is saying that the $route is not defined. I have imported the package and applied it to the best of my ability and not able to get it working.

Has anyone used this package and can see my issues?

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="start_date">Schedule Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="schedule_type" v-model="selected">
                <option value="1">Show All Projects</option>
                <option value="2">Show Scheduled Projects</option>
                <option value="3">Show Unscheduled Projects</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'hidden-mobile': isDisabled }">
                    <label class="control-label" for="start_date">Start Date (Start)</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" id="start_date" name="range[start]" :disabled="isDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6" v-bind:class="{ 'hidden-mobile': isDisabled }">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="start_date_end">Start Date (End)</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" id="start_date_end" name="range[end]" :disabled="isDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            selected: 1,
            class: ''
        }
    },
    created() {
        console.log($route.query);
    }, 
    computed: {
        isDisabled() {
          return (this.selected == 1 || this.selected == 3);
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

**Updated App.js**

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
var route = require('vue-router');
Vue.use(route);

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {

 }
});
```

Comment: Where's your root `Vue` instance? Where are you defining your `VueRouter` instance?

Comment: In my app.js file

Comment: That's funny, I can't see it anywhere

Comment: window.Vue = require('vue');

Comment: That's not a `Vue` instance, that is just including the `Vue` class into your script. Somewhere you're going to have `new route(...)` and `new Vue(...)`

Comment: I updated it my app.js

Comment: Why are you creating two `Vue` instances? Again, where is your `VueRouter` instance? Have you bothered reading the guide ~ https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html?

Comment: I'm not a front-end dev and trying to understand.

Comment: You seem to be missing a critical part where you assign your `VueRouter` instance to the `router` property of your `Vue` instance, ie `const router =
 new route({...}); const app = new Vue({..., router: router})`

Comment: The only purpose for this is in ONE Vue component

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment at all. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I only need the Vue-router to get params from a query string in a few Vue components,

Comment: Is there a way i can just use in those components.

Comment: Really not understanding what you're asking. I strongly suggest you start by reading the guides for both Vue and vue-router and read them thoroughly

Comment: I just want to include vue router for a couple of compoents

Comment: @Phil I got the router to load however I have a long query string and for some reason, all it says is fullPath as "/" even though there's a ton of params. app.dev/projects?key1=&key2=&key3=&key4=&key5=&key6...

Answer (score 3):

use this in script:

```
this.$route.path
```

only use `$route` in template like:

- inside "string interpolation, like: {{ $route.path }}
- in attribute bindings, ... .

for your case it would be:

```
created () {
    console.log(this.$route.path);
}
```

Comment: this gives me the same thing. Is what I have for my app.js correct?

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: Adding `this` definitely works [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/03614nq8ow). It must be something in app.js.